# Setting global variable in callback

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback, request

Tried to simplify my code to show my problem.

```
var rp = require('request-promise');
var ids = [];

runmyFunction();
runmyFunction();

function runmyFunction() {
    var id = 5;
    console.log("runmyFunc:  "+ids);
    if (ids.indexOf(id)==-1){
       myFunction(id);
    }
}

function myFunction(id) {
    var options = {
        uri: 'someURI'
        , headers: {
            'User-Agent': 'Request-Promise'
        }
        , json: true
    };
    rp(options)
        .then(function (response) {
            ids.push(5);
            console.log("myFunc: "+ids);
        })
        .catch(function (err) {
           console.log(err);
        });
}
```

Basically I have this function `runmyFunction`, which should only execute `myFunction` if there is not the id 12345 in it. So if I run it 10 times and the 11th the id 12345 is returned, it should stop running the function.
The problem is that the id never gets pushed in the array even if the request succeeded.

Similar problems had something to do with the request being asynchronous. Is this the cause in my code as well?

//edit I played around with it and edited the code. Current code logs this into the console:

```
runmyFunc:  
runmyFunc:  
myFunc:5
myFunc:5,5
```

So it is because it is asynchronus. Any ideas to avoid that?

Comment: Since the id's come from the request, you can never check the request ids before you actually got them. You'll need to find other logic.

Comment: Sorry, I did not make it clear that I want the function to run multiple times and stop if the id is in the array. I corrected that.

Comment: If you're calling the id's one by one, just run the check after each id arrives. if it's not 12345, let myFunction trigger itsself again. PS: have you checked if the ids are actually in the data you're receiving?

Comment: The code above is a abstraction of my real problem. I am getting a json object with a random id in it (yes it is there) and trying to check if that I do not run the function again with this id. Trying to make the code clearer again.

Comment: Can you console.log the ids array from within the then callback? I'm going to look very stupid if you can't. :)

Comment: See my recent edit. I can log it, and it does get set, but during this runmyFunc has already ran it again.

Comment: What about removing the runmyfunc function altogether and replacing the 'then' function with `function(response){ ids.push(response.data.id); if(ids.indexOf('12345') == -1) myFunction(); }` If you want to make a synchronous flow to check each id before calling the next, you don't even need promises. And yes, your current results are correct since you call runmyfunc twice before the first call returns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Shilly i found a solution by myself by adding another array.

```
var rp = require('request-promise');

var ids = [];
var idstmp = [];

runmyFunction();
runmyFunction();

function runmyFunction() {
    var id = 5;
    if (ids.indexOf(id) == -1 && idstmp.indexOf(id) == -1) {
        console.log("I was here.");
        idstmp.push(id);
        myFunction(id);
    }
}

function myFunction(id) {
    var options = {
        uri: 'someURI'
        , headers: {
            'User-Agent': 'Request-Promise'
        }
        , json: true
    };
    rp(options)
        .then(function (response) {
            idstmp.splice(idstmp.indexOf(id), 1);
            ids.push(id);
            console.log("myFunc: " + ids);
        })
        .catch(function (err) {
        idstmp.splice(idstmp.indexOf(id), 1);
        });
}
```

What this does is just adding the ids which are curently 'in use' by the request to another array so it gets block while beeing worked with. It is quite a workaround but works for me.

Answer (score 0):

not sure but i think your problem will be solved by using `.bind()` maybe help :

```
var rp = require('request-promise');
var ids = [];


function runmyFunction() {
    if (ids.indexOf(12345)==-1){
   myFunction();
   }
}

function myFunction() {
    var options = {
    uri: 'someURI'
    , headers: {
        'User-Agent': 'Request-Promise'
    }
    , json: true
};
rp(options)
    .then(function (response,mids) {
        mids.push(response.data.id);
    }.bind(ids))
    .catch(function (err) {
       console.log(err);
    });
}
```

Comment: No idea what you're trying to do here, binding changes the scope of a function (the this reference).

Comment: @Shilly i think that the problem is that in "then" function we are out of scope of "this" so i am thinking about passing "ids" array as an argument to it. that is why i said at first that i am not sure.

Comment: Does this request-promise library overwrite the standard function.bind() method? Else this makes no sense at all, since the this context is not used in the then callback.